# Spark: ClassNotFoundException while reading/ writing CSV

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, databricks

I'm trying to write a DataFrame as follows to a CSV file on HDFS

```
df.write()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/user/cloudera/csv");
```

but I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
... 21 more
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I use spark 1.6.0 with scala 2.10.5 and use the following command to submit the job

```
spark-submit --jars /path/spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar --class com.iris.Begin /path/CsvSolver.jar
```

I also have commons-csv/1.1 and commons-csv/1.5 in .m2 repository.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I guess you should remove apache commons csv from the dependency

Comment: @Ramesh The error came even when the commons dependency wasn't there

Comment: then the databricks dependency hasn't downloaded I guess. just clean the project and compile it again

Comment: @RameshMaharjan The databricks dependency was there for another version. I copied `.m2\repository\com\databricks\spark-csv_2.10` from my pc to the VM where I'm running the spark code. But I still get the same error.

Comment: why don't you compile on the VM itself then? why are you copying the repo?

Comment: can you try with commons-csv version 1.1 as defined here : http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-csv_2.11/1.5.0/spark-csv_2.11-1.5.0.pom

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Same error after clean install on the VM as well

Comment: @philantrovert Tried it. Got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add those need jars to jars folder located in spark folder ...\spark\jars\

Comment: I've added all jars. Especially the commons-csv ones, since that's where the error's coming from. It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try to search your pom dependency Hierarchy for commons-csv jar if there is any conflict of versions

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Try adding this to the pom. If that doesn't work manually download the JAR from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.5 and add using *--jars* to spark submit. That would definitely solve the problem

Comment: It's already there. The jars are there too. This is why I can't figure out why it is't working

Answer (score 0):

It's better to build fat jar that will include all your dependencies (`spark-core` should be marked as `provided`) & submit only this jar without any additional `--jars` options.

In Maven you can generate fat jar by using [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) with [predefined profile jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies). Something like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```